# Using phonegap and Android Studio 0.8.2

Tags: android, cordova, import, android-studio

There are only 3-4 articles on how to use Android Studio with Phonegap.
The problem is that these are all written for lower versions from Android Studio (<0.8) and now you can't import Phonegap projects into Android Studio without having multiple errors.

Has anyone achieved it to import a Phonegap 3.5 project into Android Studio 0.8+ and will share his/her knowledge?

**Edit:**
Ok if you don't have errors then you can describe the way you do it!

**My steps:**

1. phonegap create projectname id projectname
2. change directory into projectname
3. phonegap build android

-- so far no problems

1. start Android Studio
2. "import project"
3. choose projectname folder
4. apply the rest steps with next and finish the import
5. Android Studio now has imported my project
6. try to test the new project by go to "Run -> Run..."
7. add a new "Android Application"
8. BUT THEN in the tab "General" you have to specify a "Module" otherwise you can't start the application

Ok and from here on I stuck.
I tried to do "Build -> Make Project" but this ends with multiple errors while Android Studio tries to compile the app.

Comment: It will be difficult for people to help you if you do not explain what your errors are.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Gradle has conflicted with ant because they will generate same files. I delete the ant-build files then it works. Hope it be useful.